# All multilingual views are now MyISAM?

Tags: upgrade, database, mariadb

After the most recent CiviCRM security update to 5.56.2, a lot of my D7 sites (maybe all my multilingual ones?) are showing the old MyISAM Database Engine warning.

I took one example and discovered that it was all the civicrm db 'views' (not the drupal views) that were (now?) MyISAM. I'm using MariaDB 10.3

I did confirm that the default storage engine is InnoDB.

I presume it happened as part of the db upgrade part of the civi version upgrade, which was done via the command line using cv, i.e. cv upgrade:db

I believe the db upgrade will rebuild the views.

Anyone else have a similar experience and/or solution? Or is this not an issue and it's just a false reporting problem?

Comment: The only views I think are multilingual, and that should use the default engine. Are they from an extension?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly all the multilingual views. I can also see this issue with a D9 site with Mariadb 10.4, so it's not specific to D7 or mariadb 10.3.

Comment: Are you sure it's views? It might also be temp tables. Try `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE ENGINE = 'MyISAM' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '<your db name>' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'civicrm_%' AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'civicrm_tmp_%'` - replace "your db name"

Comment: Definitely only the views, I did a dump by table to confirm.

Comment: Ok the above sql is what civi checks to show that status check so I'm out of ideas then.

Comment: Are you saying that the civi check should be ignoring the views and that it's okay if they are MyISAM?

Comment: If you run the above does it list the views or something else?

Comment: Ah, very smart! It doesn't list views, only tables like this: civicrm_task_action_temp_* 
So I misdiagnosed what was going on, and the issue is about those temp tables that have a different than expected pattern?

Comment: And to increase my self-induced-confusion, my dump script was excluding the tmp tables, so I was misdiagnosing the problem in multiple ways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE ENGINE = 'MyISAM' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '<your db name>' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'civicrm_%' AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'civicrm_tmp_%'` - replace "your db name" - to find which tables it thinks are wrong. That is the same query the [status check uses](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/2a067f5d09e3c1fe0d2356dfa9f4d0fdd7a735a7/CRM/Core/DAO.php#L1128).

Those temp tables you're seeing in the comments above are from years ago so I'm not sure why they would show up just now, but that must be it: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12311/commits/c78f866ee1bcacd88801275c9a8ada9119e2b558

To clarify the confusion inherent in the question: MyISAM views (for multilingual sites) are expected and normal!

And, for bonus points, here's some SQL to generate a DROP statement to remove the offending old tables:

```
SELECT CONCAT( 'DROP TABLE ', GROUP_CONCAT(table_name) , ';' )  AS statement FROM information_schema.tables  WHERE ENGINE = 'MYISAM' AND table_name like 'civicrm_%';
```

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect! FWIW, the filesystem dates on those tables are from when I migrated these sites to a new server, so I suspect these tables were from a backup that wasn't configured to remove old files!

Comment: Ah that explains that.